# How can I store firebase user's uid in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I'm working on a react web application where users can sign up with an email and a password. After signing up, each user will have access to their profile data. Below is a my firebase data structure:

```
users:{
   generatedUserUID:{
            name: "User1"
            profileImage: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"
            }
     }
```

What would be the best way to store the user's uid when the user is signed in so that it can be used throughout the project. Currently, I'm using the browser's localStorage, but I'm concerned that if the client browser doesn't support localStorage then the app will be rendered useless. So, I'm looking for an alternative and not have to depend on localStorage entirely. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like Redux to manage data in your application. Redux helps you manage the state of your application.

More info here : http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: I looked into Redux too, it seems like a whole different pattern than what I'm using with react. I'll be using Redux later on but for the time being, is there any other suggestions? Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK can help out here. The `currentUser` property, accessed by `firebase.auth().currentUser`, gives you a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#uid) object containing the currently signed in user.

Check out [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) for more info.